# Reading values from python object loaded from yaml file

Tags: python, dictionary, yaml

I have a script that reads a YAML file into a python dictionary.  How do I read the values and concatenate some of them to be more meaningful?

```
#script to load the yaml file into a python object
import yaml
from yaml import load, dump
#read data from the config yaml file
with open("config.yaml", "r") as stream:
    try:
        print(yaml.load(stream))
    except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
        print(exc)
```

Contents of YAML file:

```
os2:
  host:hostname
  ip:10.123.3.182
  path:/var/log/syslog
  file:syslog
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your yaml file is incorrectly configured. There should be a space between each key and its value. You should have something like:

```
os2:
  host: hostname
  ip: 10.123.3.182
  path: /var/log/syslog
  file: syslog
```

yaml.load will return a dictionary whose values you can access normally.

```
{'os2': {'host': 'hostname', 'ip': '10.123.3.182', 'path': '/var/log/syslog', 'file': 'syslog'}}
```

Your code will look like this

```
#script to load the yaml file into a python object
import yaml
from yaml import load, dump
#read data from the config yaml file
with open("config.yaml", "r") as stream:
    try:
        config = yaml.load(stream)
        #concatenate into string
        string = f"{config['os2']['host']}@{config['os2']['ip']}:{config['os2']['path']}"
    except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
        print(exc)
```

Comment: thanks a lot! see my comment above, do you have a solution perhaps?

Comment: There should be a space between the mapping value indicator (":") and the value. You cannot just have a space between a key and its value as you suggest (but do not show), and it is also not enough to have a space before the mapping value indicator. A space is **not necessary at all** in a flow-style mapping when the keys are quoted. There is no excuse for using potentially dangerous code in your answer. `yaml.load()` is **documented** to be potentially unsafe. If the OP is an inexperienced beginner programmer and makes this error, you should always correct it and clearly indicate you did.

Answer (score 1):

Your `yaml` is inappropriately formatted.  There should be a space after the `:` in each of the sub items like so:

```
os2:
    host: hostname
    ip: 10.123.3.182
    path: /var/log/syslog
    file: syslog
```

After that if you do a `data = yaml.load(stream)` it should pass the data correctly as such:

```
{'os2': {'file': 'syslog',
         'host': 'hostname',
         'ip': '10.123.3.182',
         'path': '/var/log/syslog'}}
```

Also, you don't need the line `from yaml import load, dump` since you already `import yaml` in its entirety.

Once the data is loaded, you can do pretty much anything you wish with it.  You might want to use `str.format()` or [f strings (Python 3.6+)](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html) as such:

```
'{host}@{ip}:{path}'.format(**data['os2'])

# 'hostname@10.123.3.182:/var/log/syslog'
```

this is called [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/string.html#string-formatting) .  The `**data['os2']` bit is essentially unpacking the dictionary within `data['os2'] so you can refer to the keys directly in your string as such:

```
{'file': 'syslog',
 'host': 'hostname',
 'ip': '10.123.3.182',
 'path': '/var/log/syslog'}
```

Note that since your `yaml` doesn't include the key or value "ubuntu" there's no way for you to get reference that string unless you update your `yaml`.

Also Note: Don't confuse dictionary keys with attributes.  You cannot reference `data.os2.file` as no such attribute exist under dictionary.  You can however reference `data['os2']['file']` (note they are in strings) to retrieve the data stored.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the quick response. How do I concatenate the values to make it read like hostname@ip:path. (ubuntu@10.123.3.182:/var/log/syslog). When I use os1.file or something it doesn't work. Basically gives an error that the variable is undefined.

Comment: I have updated the answer to provide a little clarity

Comment: Thanks for that explanation too.When I use the data['os1]['file'] I get an error message -- " TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not subscriptable " , trying to debug what this could be.

Comment: awesome, used string formatting & got the info I needed. if I have a yaml file with a lot of information about servers, how can I use this such that I don't need to specify os2 or os1 and can instead use a for loop or something?                                '{host}@{ip}:{path}'.format(**data['os2']) in this line of code ? Thanks for the incredible help!

Answer (score 0):

Your YAML is perfectly normal, and it loads as you can see [here](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/?yaml=os2%3A%0A%20%20host%3Ahostname%0A%20%20ip%3A10.123.3.182%0A%20%20path%3A%2Fvar%2Flog%2Fsyslog%0A%20%20file%3Asyslog&type=json).

You have one key (`os2`) and as value, a multiline plain scalar that loads, following the YAML standard, as a string with a space where the YAML has newline+spaces. That value thus loads as `"host:hostname ip:10.123.3.182 path:/var/log/syslog file:syslog"`.

Since you indicate you expect values (multiple), you either have to introduce make the value for `os2` a flow-style mapping (in which case you **must** quote the scalars, otherwise you could e.g. not write plain URLs as scalars in valid YAML):

```
os2: {
  "host":"hostname",
  "ip":"10.123.3.182",
  "path":"/var/log/syslog",
  "file":"syslog"
  }
```

or you should follow the guideline from the [YAML standard](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2791260) that

> Normally, YAML insists the “:” mapping value indicator be separated from the value by white space.

```
os2:
  host: hostname
  ip: 10.123.3.182
  path: /var/log/syslog
  file: syslog
```

You should load YAML (when using PyYAML), using `yaml.safe_load()` as there is absolutely no need to use `yaml.load()` function, which is documented to be potentially unsafe.

With either of the above in `config.yaml`, you can do:

```
import sys
import yaml

with open('config.yaml') as stream:
    d = yaml.safe_load(stream)

os2 = d['os2']
# "concatenate" host, ip and path
print('{host}@{ip}:{path}'.format(**d['os2']))
```

to get:

```
hostname@10.123.3.182:/var/log/syslog
```